# I want form builder with bootstrap & Jquery

Tags: drag-and-drop, formbuilder

I am trying to build a form builder with bootstrap & Jquery with components  drag & drop function.

My goals:

1. Drag and Drop the Grid layout like (12 col, 8+8 col, 2+6+4 col )
2. modify the HTML form components property values
3. modify the form component events
4. modify the form component validation.

please let me know how to proceed for this project.

any open source project to reuse in this project.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Online-Drag-Drop-Form-Builder.html

Answer (score 0):

May give Formbuilder.js tool a try https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder

> Formbuilder is a graphical interface for letting users build their own webforms. Think Wufoo or Google Forms, but a lightweight component that can be integrated into your application.